# Is it safe to delete updated_at field in rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The title really says it all.  I have a Rails 3.2 app with a table of many rows, which are added but never changed or deleted.  So the default `updated_at` column isn't useful, though the `created_at` column is.  Can I safely do a migration to delete only `updated_at`?

**Addition:**  After a good pointer, I'm still plumbing for the code that creates the SQL update statements.  It's here the `created_at` column would have to be omitted if it weren't in the schema. In this app I can't afford to merely "try it" and assume that if it works in testing it will always work. I need to be absolutely sure.  The search and cross-links of the Rails source on line that I can find are not very helpful for drilling down.

Comment: My first instinct was that you'd end up with some sort of db "column not found" error, since I assumed Rails would attempt to use `updated_at` every time it needed to update something, however I'm seeing posts that say otherwise such as **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3342905/877472)**. Additionally, **[this chap](http://macdiggs.com/2008/04/18/temporarily-disable-rails-timestamp-magic-columns-updates/)** shows a way to disable timestamps for your model. I'm not putting this as an answer as I have not tested any of this, but perhaps this may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks.  I read this stuff too.  I'm hoping someone has the low-level knowledge of AR to be sure one way or the other.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually safe to do so;

Checkout line#204 from the Persitence layer of ActiveRecord : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb

It says :

> updated_at/updated_on column is updated if that column is available.

Moreover, if you dig deeper, you'll see that the `touch` method is what performs the updating of updated_at/on attributes, and it's only invoked if that column exists.

**Edit**

Digging further: the class `/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb` is responsible for timestamping the created/updated records, IF the created_at/updated_at column exist. The check is done in `Timestamp::create_record` where it builds an array of all "to timestamp columns" and loops over them. I guess the code is pretty clear if `respond_to?(column) && respond_to?("#{column}=") && self.send(column).nil? write_attribute(column.to_s, current_time)`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  The comments sound good.  I'm still groping for the code that creates the SQL `update`, where the `created_at` column would have to be omitted.  In this app I can't afford to merely "try it" and assume that if it works in testing it will always work.  I need to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Well, there's another way to see things : the class /lib/active_record/timestamp.rb is responsible for timestamping the created/updated records, IF the created_at/updated_at column exist. The check is done in Timestamp::create_record where it builds an array of all "to timestamp columns" and loops over them. I guess the code is pretty clear `if respond_to?(column) && respond_to?("#{column}=") && self.send(column).nil? write_attribute(column.to_s, current_time)`

Comment: Thanks!  That's it.  Appreciate the help. Added your note above to your answer.  Hope that's okay.  Can you say how you browse Rails code? The sites I can find don't make it very easy as, say, any Javadoc-based browser would be.

Comment: @Gene Thank you for that ! I have https://github.com/rails/rails on my local machine; I usually just `grep` over it.
If something interests me, I check the pretty-printed APIDoc on http://api.rubyonrails.org (notice the show|github links below each method).

Comment: Yeah. Thought of doing that.  Seems so 1970's...  Thanks again.  The problem with the API docs is they (at least seem to) only cover the API functions themselves.  The deeper stuff isn't there.